# PHP - Associative array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Consider the structure for an associative array and a function which are composed by structure below:

```
$myCars = array("name" => "categories", "data" => array());

function getCategoriesData()
{

    // data is gathered here

    return $categoriesData
}
```

The “data” array should be populated with the return of the “getCategoriesData” function.
Considering that, how can I perform that action using a foreach loop?

Comment: "The “data” array should be populated with the return of the “getCategoriesData” function", in order to be able to answer the question we have to know what this function returns.

Comment: Do you want data array to be populated when getCategoriesData called and returned or array element to be inserted to data array each time the function is called and returned?

Comment: I just want to populate the "data" array with the return of the "getCategoriesData".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `getCategoriesData()` returns an Array, if you specifically need to use a `foreach` loop, we can write the code like this

```
$returnedArray = getCategoriesData();

foreach($returnedArray as $key => $value)
{
    $myCars["data"][$key] = $value;
}
```

An even simpler approach would be this.

```
$mycars["data"] = getCategoriesData();
```